# Find max elements in the column of 2D table,create new table from them and print it

Tags: java

Hello I am new in java and I want to write a program where I will print the max element from the column in 2D table.With this code I get out of bounds
 I am updating a picture to show what actually I want to print.

[image]

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int col = sc.nextInt();
int row = sc.nextInt();

int[][] table = new int [col][row];
int[]   t     = new int [row];


 for(int i=0; i<col; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<row; j++){
     table[i][j] = sc.nextInt();                   
     }
}
   int max= 0;
for(int i=0; i<col; i++){
    int m = 0;
    max = table[0][i];
    for(int j=0; j<row; j++){
        if(max<table[j][i]){
            max = table[j][i];
            t[m] = table[j][i];
            m++;
        }
    }
}      
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t));
```

Comment: Hi again! Please add also the content of the file you're using.

Comment: format your code and use line by line debugger to see whats you are doing on every line. SO is not your homework solver site :(

Comment: It is not homework. I am trying to learn ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to address two things in your code:

1. Remove `t[m] = table[j][i];` from of inner loop and assign `max` to `t[i]` outside the inner loop.
2. Remove `m` as it is useless.

The complete code as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][]table=new int[][]{
            {10,-6,-5,1},
            {0,-1,-7,-3},
            {9,5,-4,7},
            {8,3,-3,7},
            {4,2,-6,9}
        };

        int max;
        int[] t=new int[table[0].length];
        for(int i=0; i<table[0].length; i++){           
            max = table[0][i];
            for(int j=0; j<table.length; j++){
                if(max<table[j][i]){
                    max = table[j][i];                  
                }
            }
            t[i]=max;
        } 

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[10, 5, -3, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. In your code `m` can be incremented more than once per column.

```java
int[][] table = new int [row][col];
int[]   t     = new int [col];
for(int i=0; i<row; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<col; j++){
     table[i][j] = sc.nextInt();                   
     }
}
for(int i=0; i<col; i++){
    int m = 0;
    max = table[0][i];
    for(int j=0; j<row; j++){
        if(max<table[j][i]){
            max = table[j][i];
        }
    }
    t[i] = max;
}
```